# bash script file copied with additional character in filename

Tags: linux, bash

I am writing a bash script to copy some config files. I run the file using `sudo bash configure.sh`.

```
#!/bin/bash
cp config/ocr_pattern /usr/share/tesseract-ocr/tessdata/ocr_pattern
cp config/ocr_config /usr/share/tesseract-ocr/tessdata/tessconfigs/ocr_config
```

However when I view the changes made, `ocr_config` is copied correctly but `ocr_pattern` is copied with `ocr_pattern?` as the filename instead of `ocr_pattern`. There is an additional character `?` behind in the filename for `ocr_pattern`. What is the issue here?

```
cat -A

#!/bin/bash^M
cp config/ocr_pattern /usr/share/tesseract-ocr/tessdata/ocr_pattern^M
cp config/ocr_config /usr/share/tesseract-ocr/tessdata/tessconfigs/ocr_config
```

Comment: Do you have three periods in your code?  If so, you shouldn't

Comment: I don't understand your question - perhaps you could clarify it a bit

Comment: You may have a stray trailing character after **file1** in your script.

Comment: post the exact code.

Comment: Whats the output of `cat -A configure.sh`?

Comment: Your file may have DOS `\r\n` line endings. Check with `cat -v`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As shown by the output of `cat -A`, you have carriage return (`\r`) at the end of some lines causing the mentioned issues.

Remove those:

```
sed -i 's/\r$//' configure.sh
```

or just use `dos2unix`:

```
dos2unix configure.sh
```